# How to extract values from for loop

Tags: r, loops, extract

My code is given below. The code produces `g` values more than once, say `g1`, `g2` etc. What I want to do is to extract these g values from the loop and use it out of the loop. Any idea how to do so?

```
I<-1        
S<-10       
h<-1        
lmd<-1      
v<-2            
n<-100  

A=as.integer((S-I)/h)       

U=A+1           

Sha=(A*h)+I     

sindeg=seq(from = I, to =Sha, length.out =U)    

D=((lmd)^v)*(((sindeg)^(-v))-((sindeg+h)^(-v)))     

tn=(as.integer(n*D))                        

for(i in 1:A){
print(paste(tn[i]))


atn=tn[i]
k=sindeg[i]+h
m=sindeg[i]
print(paste("alt",m))
print(paste("üst",k))

g=runif(atn, m, k)

print(paste(g))

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your point, you can put the current g values to an external (compared to the loop) list, for example here extg :

```
I<-1        
S<-10       
h<-1        
lmd<-1      
v<-2            
n<-100  

A=as.integer((S-I)/h)       

U=A+1           

Sha=(A*h)+I     

sindeg=seq(from = I, to =Sha, length.out =U)    

D=((lmd)^v)*(((sindeg)^(-v))-((sindeg+h)^(-v)))     

tn=(as.integer(n*D))                        

extg = list()

for(i in 1:A)
{
    print(paste(tn[i]))


    atn=tn[i]
    k=sindeg[i]+h
    m=sindeg[i]
    print(paste("alt",m))
    print(paste("üst",k))

`   g=runif(atn, m, k)

    extg[[i]] = g

    print(paste(g))
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can use iteration functions such as functions from `purrr` instead of raw for loops. Here using `map2` to iterate on `tn` and `sindeg`

```
library(purrr)
gs <- map2( tn, sindeg, function(atn, m) {
  runif(atn, m, m + h )
})
```